# LUN type for SQL Server on an FSx system

Tags: iscsi, amazon-fsx

I want to setup and connect a LUN running on my FSx ONTAP file server to my SQL Server cluster. I see different types for the lun configuration: windows/windows_gpt/windows_2008.

What is the recommended type for best SQL performance? It must support MBR and GPT partitioning methods.

Multiple lun types are available but need to figure out best one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see specifically about how to achieve I/O alignment using LUN OS types - https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/san-admin/io-misalignments-properly-aligned-luns-concept.html#achieve-io-alignment-using-lun-os-types

Having listed that reference, it is most likely that you will want
Windows_2008 ostype as it is the recommended type for any Windows server version newer than 2008, and both MBR and GPT partitioning methods are supported (See https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196995/html/GUID-7D4DD6E3-DB77-4671-BDA2-E393002E9EB2.html)

In general I would also recommend reviewing best practices for MS SQL on FSX ONTAP - https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/netapp-solutions/databases/sql-aws-ec2.html#introduction

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2019, so that recommendation should be good.  Thanks for the links.